# Tizen Socket.io connection only works on 5.0

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

So I have a problem where my app only runs on 5.0 simulator.
Ive tested the app on 4.0 - 5.0 - 5.5 - & 6.0.

The project was first created on 5.0 but I then re-did it on v 4.0 but still the same problem.

I'm thinking it has something to do with socket connection but why would it only work for 5.0?
All I'm changing when testing is to choose a different emulator version.

INDEX

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Scheduled-countdown"/>

    <title>Scheduled-countdown</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>     
</head>

<body>
  <div class=container>
    
    
    <div class=centerContainer>
        <div id=ipInput style="height:100%">
<!--            Storage key:
           <input type="text" id="storageKey" style="width: 50px"/> -->
           ipAdress:
           <input type="text" id="storageData" style="width: 50%"/>
           <input type="button" id="save" value="SAVE" onclick="addStorage(); return false;"/>
           <h1 id="ipAdress">No Save ipAdress</h1>
        </div>
        
        
        
        <div id="currentTime"></div>
        <div id="title"></div>
        <div id="time"></div>
    </div>
  </div>  

</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
          let countDownBool;
          let bgColor;
    
        var ipAdress = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key("ipAdress"))
        console.log(ipAdress)
        var ipString = `http://192.168.8.124:3000`
        console.log(ipString)
        ipAdress.textContent = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key("ipAdress"))
        
        
        const socket = io(ipString,{path: '/ws',});
        
        
        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('SocketConnected!');
            document.getElementById("ipInput").style.display = "none";
            
            
        });
        
        socket.on('message', (data) => {
            const { type, message } = data;
            //console.log(type);
            
            if (type == "currentTime") {
                document.getElementById("currentTime").textContent = message;
                
                if (countDownBool){
                    //style.display = "block"; style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("currentTime").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("title").style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("time").style.display = "block";
                    
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("currentTime").style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("title").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("time").style.display = "none";
                }
                //console.log("currentTime");
                
            }
            
            if (type == "countDown") {
                document.getElementById("title").textContent = message.title;
                document.getElementById("time").textContent = message.time;
                
                if(message.bool){
                    countDownBool = true;
                    
                    
                    if (message.countDownTimeInMS > (-3*60000) && message.countDownTimeInMS < 0) {
                        bgColor = message.colors.countDownColor;
                    }else if(message.countDownTimeInMS > 0){
                        bgColor = message.colors.countUpColor;
                    }
                    
                    //-------------------
                      if(message.countDownTimeInMS > (-5*60000) && message.countDownTimeInMS < (-5*60000+1000)){
                      console.log("Vibrate 5");
                        navigator.vibrate([100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]);
                      }
                      if(message.countDownTimeInMS > (-4*60000) && message.countDownTimeInMS < (-4*60000+1000)){
                      console.log("Vibrate 4");
                        navigator.vibrate([100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]);
                      }
                      if(message.countDownTimeInMS > (-3*60000) && message.countDownTimeInMS < (-3*60000+1000)){
                      console.log("Vibrate 3");
                         navigator.vibrate([100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]);
                      }
                      if(message.countDownTimeInMS > (-2*60000) && message.countDownTimeInMS < (-2*60000+1000)){
                      console.log("Vibrate 2");
                         navigator.vibrate([100, 100, 100, 100]);
                      }
                      if(message.countDownTimeInMS > (-1*60000) && message.countDownTimeInMS < (-1*60000+1000)){
                      console.log("Vibrate 1");
                         navigator.vibrate([100, 100]);
                      }
                      if(message.countDownTimeInMS > (0) && message.countDownTimeInMS < (0+1000)){
                      console.log("Vibrate START");
                         navigator.vibrate([1000, 100, 1000, 100]);
                      }
                    //-------------------
                    
                }else{
                    countDownBool = false;
                    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "2b2b2b";
                }
    
            }
        });
        
    </script>
    
    <script>
        function addStorage() {
            //var key = document.getElementById('storageKey');
            var key = "ipAdress";
            var data = document.getElementById('storageData');
            
    
            /* Set the local storage item */
            if ('localStorage' in window) {
                localStorage.setItem(key.value, data.value);
                location.reload();
            } else {
                alert('no localStorage in window');
            }
    
            /* Set the session storage item */
            if ('sessionStorage' in window) {
                sessionStorage.setItem(key.value, data.value);
                location.reload();
            } else {
                alert('no sessionStorage in window');
            }
        }
    </script>

</html>
```

CONFIG

```
S<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" id="http://yourdomain/ScheduledCountdownTizen4" version="1.0.0" viewmodes="maximized">
    <access origin="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com" subdomains="true"/>
    <tizen:application id="YGGUZsElLs.ScheduledCountdownTizen4" package="YGGUZsElLs" required_version="4.0"/>
    <author href="https://github.com/mattehalen/Scheduled-countdown" email="matte_halen@hotmail.com">Mathias Halén</author>
    <tizen:background-category value="background-network"/>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.all"/>
    <icon src="icon.png"/>
    <name>ScheduledCountdownTizen4</name>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
    <tizen:profile name="wearable"/>
    <tizen:setting background-support="enable" encryption="disable" hwkey-event="enable"/>
</widget>
```

Comment: Can you post server code also so that I can see?

Comment: The server isn’t my. https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift

Comment: The url seems to be a socket.io client code. Do you have a server code?

Comment: i use this one as a nodejs server.
https://github.com/mattehalen/Scheduled-countdown
https://github.com/mattehalen/Scheduled-countdown/releases/tag/Alpha_V.0.0.2

Comment: So the problem is that on every version except 5.0 I'm getting blocked by WARP.
The solution is simple in the first step of the app but not the final product.

You see. The Watch needs to connect to a local server where the IP changes depending on where we run the server. If I run the server at home my local address is not the same as at work.

The app should be able to connect to a local server but that might not be possible?

Comment: Can you check with <access origin="http://192.168.8.124:3000" subdomains="true"/> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with your access origin.
`<access origin="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com" subdomains="true"/>`
You should either modify your access origin to your IP String (192.168.8.124)
`<access origin="192.168.8.124:3000" subdomains="true"/>`
or make it *
`<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>`